# Applying setRotation to Maps API v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I need to create tilted view in Maps API v2. I know that API v2 have [feature](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/views#tilt_viewing_angle) to tilt the view, but that's not enough for my use (I need 70-75 degrees), so I tried to use [.setRotationX](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setRotationX%28float%29) method.

When I apply rotation, the view itself is shortened (which means that some sort of rotation is applied), but map tiles (I only need satellite view) stay in same position. I also tried overriding .onDraw methods with applying rotation directly to canvas, but no luck.

In Maps API v1, setRotationX works as intended, tiles are tilted and I get some sort of 3D/depth perspective I need, but I have some other issues, so I am trying to use API v2 instead.

Comment: Given that the UI for a Maps V2 map is actually rendered in another process, with the bits shipped back for display in yours, and that the result is shown on a `SurfaceView`, the fact that you cannot get this to work does not surprise me.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I wasn't sure how exactly API v2 works, but now that you have explained, it really sounds impossible :(

Comment: @CommonsWare you should put in that as answer.

Comment: @Warpzt I already did see my answer

Answer (score 0):

The feature you are looking for is not available in V2 off the maps api. Neither is it available in version 3.12.